# Dropdown List In CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, cloudpage

I am trying to create a dropdown list in the cloud page, but the question is, how do we pass the dropdown value to another cloud page?

I've created a dropdown , and what it does here is it fetches the value from my DE.
the next step I need to do is to pass the 'selected' dropdown value to another cloud page which I am not really sure how to do that, would appreciate help here!

```
%%[
SET @IndividualDE = "One"
SET @Ind_rows = LookupRows("Teamx_Unsubscribe_List", "Group", @IndividualDE)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@Ind_rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
  if @i == 1 then
output(concat('Select Individual:  ','<select name="individual" style="width:100%;"id="individual" onchange="selectIndividual(event)"><option value="">Please select reason</option>'))
endif

var @Indname
set @Indname_row = row(@Ind_rows,@i)
set @Indname = field(@Indname_row,"Unsub_Name")
output(concat('<option value="', @Indname, '">', @Indname, '</option>'))

 if @i == @rowCount then
        output(concat('</select>'))
      endif
      
         next @i          
else

output(concat("<br>companies not found"))

endif 
]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to wrap it in a html form tag and define the page where the data should be posted, like this.

Replace `url of the target page` with an actual url below:

```
%%[
SET @IndividualDE = "One"
SET @Ind_rows = LookupRows("Teamx_Unsubscribe_List", "Group", @IndividualDE)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@Ind_rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
  if @i == 1 then
output(concat('Select Individual:  ','<form action="url of the target page" method="post"><select name="individual" style="width:100%;"id="individual" onchange="selectIndividual(event)"><option value="">Please select reason</option>'))
endif

var @Indname
set @Indname_row = row(@Ind_rows,@i)
set @Indname = field(@Indname_row,"Unsub_Name")
output(concat('<option value="', @Indname, '">', @Indname, '</option>'))

 if @i == @rowCount then
        output(concat('</select><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>'))
      endif
      
         next @i          
else

output(concat("<br>companies not found"))

endif 
]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Then, you can either create a separate page with a form handler, or you can post the form data into the same page and process it there. This article will give you more details on creating and processing form data with AMPscript: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/

Then, given your drop down list is called `individual`, you can retrieve the selected values like this on your form handler page:

```
%%[
  set @individual = RequestParameter("individual")
 
]%%
```

More on the RequestParameter function: https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/

Comment: thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have used following above script and trying to display the value in a new cloud page.It is directing to a new page but value is not being displayed.Once I get the selected value from drop down I would like to display all the matching records based on the selected value in a table format

This is my code

Audit Logs

#Audit_div { width: 300px; height: 50px; text-align: right; left: 100px; position: relative; }
#Category_div { width: 300px; height: 50px; text-align: right; left: 100px; position: relative; }



Audit Logs Page

%%[
var @Asset_rows, @Asset_row, @rowCount, @i
set @Asset_rows = LookupRows("Adv_Audit_trail_Logs_DEV", "default", "1")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@Asset_rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
if @i == 1 then
output(concat('Select AssetName:  ','<select name="AssetName" style="width:100%;"id="AssetName" onchange="selectAssetName(event)">Please select AssetName'))
endif

var @Asset
set @Asset_row = row(@Asset_rows,@i)
set @Asset = field(@Asset_row,"AssetName")
output(concat('', @Asset, ''))

if @i == @rowCount then
output(concat(''))
endif

```
     next @i
```

else

output(concat("
companies not found"))

endif
]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%